# Cuda Sieve of Eratosthenes Error when larger than 1000000

Tags: c++, cuda, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am new to cuda and am trying to use it to carry out the Sieve of Eratosthenes. The code works for primes below 1000000. Above it i get an unknown kernal launch error. Now I understand this is because I am trying to launch a grid with too many blocks. However if I set the blocks to 1000 I do not get all the prime numbers. I think there may be an issue with the indexing in the kernal but not sure.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

__global__ static void Sieve(long * sieve, long sieve_size)
{
int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

if (idx > 1) {
    for (int i = idx+idx; i < sieve_size; i += idx) {

        sieve[i] = 1;
    }
}
}

int main()
{

long  *device_sieve;
long *host_sieve = new long[4000000];
ofstream data("data.csv", ofstream::out);

double sieve_size = 4000000 / sizeof(long);

cudaSetDevice(0);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
cudaThreadSynchronize();
cudaMalloc((void**)&device_sieve, sizeof(long) * sieve_size);

cudaError_t error1 = cudaGetLastError();
cout << "1" << cudaGetErrorString(error1) << endl;

int block = sqrt(sieve_size);

Sieve << <1, block >> >(device_sieve, sieve_size);
cudaThreadSynchronize();
cudaMemcpy(host_sieve, device_sieve, sizeof(long) * sieve_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

cudaError_t error = cudaGetLastError();
cout << "2" << cudaGetErrorString(error) << endl;
cudaFree(device_sieve);

for (int i = 2; i < sieve_size; ++i)
    if (host_sieve[i] == 0)
        data << i << endl;

getchar();
cout << "DONE" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of issues with your code. First of all, the line `double sieve_size = 4000000 / sizeof(long);` doesn't make sense, since that leads to allocating insufficient amount of memory on the GPU.

Take an example of having 8 numbers, each 8 bytes long (which is the standard size of long afaik), so putting them into an array takes up 64 bytes of memory. that would mean that your `double sieve_size = 8/sizeof(long)` would hold value `1`. And then you are allocating `sieve_size*sizeof(long)` bytes of memory on GPU, which in this case means you're allocating 8 bytes, while you need 64 as in the initial array. So drop the division.

Another thing is that I don't think it is a good idea to use `double` to represent some amount of memory even though it might not generate a compilation error, it might possibly lead to issues with precision rounding, when you allocate just a couple bytes too little and thus invoke a segmentation fault (if you need to represent discrete entities such as a size of a block of memory or length of an array, integer types are the logical choice). So I would change the line to:

```
long sieve_size = 4000000;
```

Now another thing is that there are limits on the size of a block that you can execute. It varies by architecture and you can find the specifics of your using command `cudaGetDeviceProperties`. As far as I know on most modern cards the limitations are `1024 max threads per block`. So you can execute either block of size `32x32x1` or `1024x1x1` etc. If you need to process more data you will have to use a bigger grid than just `1x1x1`.

Hope this helps!